# How to do deterministic builds of Docker images?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build Docker images and I would like my Docker images to be deterministic. Much to my surprise I found that even a trivial Dockerfile such as

```
FROM scratch
ENV a b
```

Produces different IDs when built repeatedly using `docker build --no-cache .`

How could I make my builds deterministic and whats causing the changes in image IDs? When caching is enabled the same ID is produced.

The reason I'm trying to get this reproducibility is to enable producing the same layers in a distributed build environment. I can not control where a build is run therefore I can not know what is in the cache.
Also the Docker build downloads files using wget from an ftp which may or may not have changed, currently I can not easily tell Docker from within a Dockerfile if the results of a `RUN` should invalidate the cache. Therefore if I could just produce the same ID for identical layers (when no cache is used) these layers would not have to be "push"ed and "pull"ed again.

Also all the reasons listed here: https://reproducible-builds.org/

Comment: why do you want this behavior? If you just want to reference an image for sure, tag it use `docker build -t tag .`

Comment: What this behavior impact you?

Comment: When caching is enabled I think the daemon does not create a new image. The daemon detects that the layers are the same, and so it doesn't build a new image.

Comment: I edited the question and provided my use case.

Comment: But why do you *need* to tell Docker if the cache should be invalidated or not? Docker can figure out this by itself

Comment: Docker can't know if a wget command would download the same content that is already in cache or not (same for apt get for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, currently docker images do not hash to byte-exact hashes, since the metadata currently contains stateful information such as created date. You can check out the [design doc from 1.10](https://gist.github.com/aaronlehmann/b42a2eaf633fc949f93b#id-definitions-and-calculations). Unfortunately, it looks like the history metadata is an important part of image validity and identification.

Don't get me wrong, I'm all about reproducible builds. However I don't believe hash-exactness is the best criteria for measuring reproducibility of a docker image. A docker image isn't a compiled binary. There is no way to guarantee the results of a stage will ever be able to be reproduced, so even if the datetime metadata was absent, it would not guarantee reproducible builds. Take this pathological example:

```
RUN curl "https://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&len=20&digits=on&unique=on&format=plain&rnd=new" -o nonce.txt
```

Comment: The nice thing about hash-exactness is that implies other forms of exactness and it is easy to test. As compared to say "identical behaviour" which is at times a halting problem!

Comment: Precisely. Docker images are a way to *support* reproducibility. They are more portable (than local compiles), less coupled (than system dynamic linked libraries), more reproducible, but they aren't absolutely portable, decoupled, or reproducible, because like you say, that requires defining absolute behavior, which is an incomplete Entscheidungsproblem :p

Comment: Lol, "In this paper we solve a restricted variant of the halting problem by showing that identical programs on a turing machine produce the same output" :)

Answer (score 2):

The image ID is a SHA256 of the image's configuration object (what you get when you do a `docker image inspect`). Run this with the images you are creating and you will see differences between them.